# How can I flag records where the sum of two years earnlosssave is zero using Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, case, filtering

I am trying to flag IDs where the sum of two years earnloss is less than or equal to zeio.  I've tried using case statements because I want to flag them as lost money both years, but I am seeing cases where one id shows 1 year of loss too.

id      year  earnsaveloss flag 
"A1006" 2021    0         "Lost money both years" 
"A1006" 2022    0         "Lost money both years" 
**"A1023"   2021    0         "Lost money both years" single year with
less than or equal to zero**

"A1026" 2021    0         "Lost money both years" 
"A1026" 2022    0         "Lost money both years" 
**"A1052"   2021    0         "Lost money both years"  single year with
less than or equal to zero

"A1070" 2022    0         "Lost money both years" single year with
less than or equal to zero

"A1080" 2021    0         "Lost money both years" single year with
less than or equal to zero**

"A1131" 2021    0         "Lost money both years" 
"A1131" 2022    0         "Lost money both years" 
"A1175" 2021    0         "Lost money both years" 
"A1199" 2021    0         "Lost money both years" 
"A1199" 2022    0         "Lost money both years"

```
SELECT
id,year,earnsaveloss,
CASE
    WHEN
        (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM mssp_2021_2022_aco 
        WHERE year = 2021 AND earnsaveloss = 0 ) > 0
        AND
        (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM mssp_2021_2022_aco 
        WHERE year = 2022 AND earnsaveloss = 0 ) > 0
    THEN 'Lost money both years'
    ELSE ''
END AS NoMoneyBothYears
```

FROM mssp_2021_2022_aco
WHERE earnsaveloss <= 0
ORDER BY id,year

I expect to only list only ids that have a sum of less than or equal to zero for both 2021 and 2022, however the code listed shows ids where at least one year had less than or equal to zero.

Comment: Are you using Mysql and what version?

Comment: Try moving your (  ) around to fix the boolean logic.  You have it test for ( first part ) but then do another thing of >  .. you need the whole logic to fit into the (   ) if that makes sense.

Comment: @easleyfixed I'm using postgressql

Comment: I updated your question to reflect that, as soon as a mod sees the change it will be updated, and perhaps more people will see it, unfortunately i use MySQL but maybe someone can have the correct POSTGRE for you in a bit.

Comment: I think you need the (   ) to encompass the ENTIRE thing  .. instead of (  this ) AND ( that  ) it needs to be where (  this   AND that     ) ... that make sense?